# setTimeout before setImmediate

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, timeout, settimeout

this code prints that setTimeout is before setImmediate. Why is it so? I thought that all setImmediates are run before setTimeouts.

```
setImmediate(function() {
    console.log("i");
});

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("t");
}, 0);

var i;
for (i = 0 ; i < 3000000000 ; ++i) {}
```

Comment: Is this being run on node? Or which browser?

Comment: It's run in node v5.2.0

Answer (score 0):

According to [NodeJS Event Loop docs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#setimmediate-vs-settimeout):

> If both are called from within the main module, then timing will be bound by the performance of the process (which can be impacted by other applications running on the machine).

However there's a case where this behaviour is indeed what happens: if you move the two calls within an I/O cycle, the immediate callback is always executed first:

```
// timeout_vs_immediate.js
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile(__filename, () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('timeout');
  }, 0);
  setImmediate(() => {
    console.log('immediate');
  });
});
```